# Fundamental group of the configuration space in a plane

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $C_n$ be the set of unordered distinct $n$-tuples in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$C_n= \left\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in (\mathbb{R}^2)^n \mid x_i\neq x_j \text{ for }i\neq j \right\}/S_n .$$

I wish to prove that its fundamental group $\pi_1(C_n)=B_n$, where $B_n$ is the Artin braid group on $n$ strands.

While there are probably various standard techniques for computing fundamental group, I do not know which I should look out for. Therefore, I am looking for a sketch of the proof, or a list of key concepts/theorems I should read up on.

Comment: This is, more or less, by the definition of the braid group: If you have a braid (say, going from a plane at height 0 to a plane at height 1), you can intersect it with parallel planes at height t, to get a closed path in the configuration space of the plane. Depending on the exact definition of a braid, this even defines a homeomorphism from the space of closed loops (with given starting point) in the configuration space of the plane to the space of braids. In particular, we get a bijection of the sets of components - the fundamental group of the configuration space and the braid group.

Comment: Look at Birman, "Braids, Links, and Mapping Class Groups"

Comment: This seems more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to follow this up with a seemingly related question. In my book "Topology and groupoids" (2006) there is a whole Chapter 11 on *Orbit Spaces, Orbit Groupoids*, giving joint work with P.J. Higgins showing that for discontinuous actions of a discrete group on a Hausdorff space which has a universal cover, the

*fundamental groupoid of the orbit space is the orbit groupoid of the fundamental groupoid*.

One application  is given there, namely computing the fundamental group of the symmetric square of a space $X$ (it is the fundamental group of $X$ made abelian, which of course is known through other routes). A question arising from this work  is whether there are applications of these methods to braid groups, and configuration spaces. I'd like to see a really novel application!